# How can I arrange linear equation with "Collect" in Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, programming, linear-algebra

I was asked a question about the order of linear equations and got this code(@halirutan ) to arrange the equation :

```
    plus /: MakeBoxes[plus[args__], form_] := 
 With[{niceFormatting = 
    RowBox[Riffle[MakeBoxes[#, form] & /@ {args}, "+"]]}, 
  InterpretationBox[niceFormatting, Plus[args]]]
```

where

```
Subscript[R, 2] := Subscript[a, 2] t + Subscript[b, 2];
Subscript[R, 3] := Subscript[a, 3] t + Subscript[b, 3];

poly = Expand[Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 3]]

TraditionalForm[poly /. Plus :> plus]
```

The order of the equation shall be
$$a_2 a_3 t^2+ a_3 b_2t+a_2 b_3t+b_2 b_3$$

I need to add a restrcuturing (`Collect`) in the code

In my attempts I suggested it be so

```
poly = Collect[Expand[Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 3]],t]
```

$$a_2 a_3 t^2+b_2 b_3+t \left(a_3 b_2+a_2 b_3\right)$$

but,It does not result in the desired result.
I want him to be in this configuration
$$a_2 a_3 t^2+ \left(a_2 b_3+a_3 b_2\right)t+b_2 b_3$$

To arrange linear equations in general. As an example
[image]
Do you have any help or suggestions ?

Comment: @halirutan  can you help me

Comment: You should understand how this code works, the code prevents `TraditionalForm` from rearranging terms. However, the expression you got from `Collect` is already of that form, so this code will do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since it is J.M.'s answer.

```
SetOptions[PolynomialForm, TraditionalOrder -> True]; Collect[poly, t] // PolynomialForm
```

Comment: Since this is J.M.'s comment, it should be acknowledged in the answer.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Sorry just my intention was that the best answer

Comment: @Emadkareem You should make this community wiki since it is J.M.'s answer.

Comment: @happyfish How to do it. Do you delete the answer? I am a beginner in mathematica.stackexchange.

Comment: @Emadkareem simply edit your question, and check the "community wiki" box [in this position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JP7L.png)

Answer (score 5):

You can use function `Exponent` to get the power of `t` and sort it. With some small modifications, you can obtain this.

```
expr = Collect[Expand[Subscript[R, 2] Subscript[R, 3]], t];
(expr /. Plus -> plus // Reverse@*SortBy[Exponent[#, t] &]) // TraditionalForm
```

$$ a_2 a_3 t^2+t\left(a_3 b_2+a_2 b_3\right)+b_2 b_3$$
If you are not satisfied with the position of `t`, I will try to modify it.

### Update

This strange ordering is caused by the usage of `Subscript`. I have made a more general function, that prints out the form as if no subscript is used

```
normalOrder[expr_] := 
 Reverse@HoldForm[
    Evaluate[
     expr /. Subscript[a_, b_] :> 
       ToString[a] <> "$" <> ToString[b]]] /. 
  a_?(StringQ@# && StringMatchQ[#, __ ~~ "$" ~~ __] &) :> 
   RuleCondition[
    Subscript @@ ToExpression /@ StringSplit[ToString[a], "$"]]
```

The result is as follows:

```
normalOrder[poly]//TraditionalForm
```

$$b_2 b_3+a_3 b_2 t+a_2 b_3 t+a_2 a_3 t^2$$

```
normalOrder[Collect[poly, t]]//TraditionalForm
```

$$b_2 b_3+\left(a_3 b_2+a_2 b_3\right) t+a_2 a_3 t^2$$

### Update2

If you must have terms sorted by the power of $t$ in reverse order,

```
normalOrderReverse[expr_] := 
 Module[{foo}, 
  HoldForm[Evaluate[
       expr /. Subscript[a_, b_] :> 
         ToString[a] <> "$" <> ToString[b]]] /. 
     Verbatim[Plus][a___] :> RuleCondition[Reverse@foo[a]] /. 
    foo -> Plus /. 
   a_?(StringQ@# && StringMatchQ[#, __ ~~ "$" ~~ __] &) :> 
    RuleCondition[
     Subscript @@ ToExpression /@ StringSplit[ToString[a], "$"]]]
```

Now

```
normalOrderReverse[poly] // TraditionalForm
```

$$a_2 a_3 t^2+a_2 b_3 t+a_3 b_2 t+b_2 b_3$$

```
normalOrderReverse[Collect[poly, t]] // TraditionalForm
```

$$a_2 a_3 t^2+\left(a_3 b_2+a_2 b_3\right) t+b_2 b_3$$

Actually that `Reverse` can be replaced to use other sorting functions.

Comment: thanks for your efforts . But I am arranging the equation according to the logic of mathematics .... It must have a variable t that holds the upper powers at first ,where $a_i,b_i$ are constant ,$i=2,3,...$

Comment: @Emadkareem so you mean you want $t^2$ term at the first place?

Comment: ...like this $$a_2 a_3 t^2+\left(a_3 b_2+a_2 b_3\right) t+b_2 b_3$$

Comment: @Emadkareem ok, I am done

Comment: ...Thank you. I am grateful to you for helping me

Comment: Try this: `SetOptions[PolynomialForm, TraditionalOrder -> True]; Collect[poly, t] // PolynomialForm`

Comment: @J.M. Ahh, I don't know such a form exists...

Comment: @Emadkareem You should use what J.M. suggested, clearly a builtin is cleaner and safer

Comment: It's *undocumented*, tho, so *caveat emptor* as always.

Comment: @J.M. You should post that as an answer, so others can get to the right solution easily. Otherwise they could be confused by my spaghetti code...

Comment: I'd prefer that you append this to your answer... :)